# Angular 2 HTTP Post using Json-server is not working

Tags: json, angular, http

I am learning angular 2 and now i am creating a self teaching project like online ticket booking. In that, i have a screen to book a
new ticket. I have configured JSon-server mock to get and post the
data for my application.

I have a service to get and post the data as like below

```
import { Injectable, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core'
import { Http, Response, Headers,  RequestOptions } from '@angular/http'

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { UserInfo } from './userInfo.model'
import { DataModel } from './data.model'

Injectable()
export class UserInfoService implements OnInit {

    userInfo: UserInfo;
    dataModel: DataModel;
    constructor( @Inject(Http) private _http: Http) {
        this.userInfo = new UserInfo();
        this.dataModel = new DataModel();
    }

    setUserInfo(userName: string, loggedIn: boolean, action: string): UserInfo {
        this.userInfo.userName = userName;
        this.userInfo.isLoggedIn = loggedIn;
        this.userInfo.process = action;
        return this.userInfo;
    }
    setProcess(action: string) {
        this.userInfo.process = action;
    }
    getUserInfo(): UserInfo {
        return this.userInfo;
    }

    fetchJSONdata(requiredType: string) {
        console.log('param' + requiredType);
        return this._http.get("http://localhost:3000/" + requiredType).map((res: Response) => <DataModel[]>res.json())
            .do(data => console.log(requiredType + '-> Retrive Data:' + JSON.stringify(data)));
    }
    // Passing requiredType as "bookings"
    **pushJSONData**(requiredType: string, _dataModel: DataModel) {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(_dataModel); // Stringify payload
        let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });  
        let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 

        return this._http.post("http://localhost:3000/" + requiredType, _dataModel, options)  
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json())  
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')).do(data => console.log(data)); 
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

And here is my data model

```
export class DataModel {
    userid : string;
    password:string;
    mail: string;
    city: string;
    address: string;
    from: string;
    to: string;
    date:Date;
    transportname:string;
    pnr: string;
    tickets: string;
    about: string;
    name: string;
    company: string;
    phonenumber: string;
    rule:string;
    faq:string
}
```

the data which i am passing from the screen is

```
DataModel {from: "ssssss", to: "dddddd", date: "2017-06-08", transportname: "fffffff", tickets: "gggggggggg"…}
```

Data from the JSON-Server mock in the url [http://localhost:3000/bookings][1]

```
[
  {
    "from": "",
    "to": "",
    "transportname": "Ng-Travels",
    "pnr": "",
    "tickets": "",
    "date": ""
  }
]
```

And finally my DB.json file

```
"bookings": [
        {
            "from": "",
            "to": "",
            "transportname": "Ng-Travels",
            "pnr": "",
            "tickets": "",
            "date": ""
        }
    ]
```

My problem is now when i try to post the data using the **pushJSONData** function from the **UserInfoService** class (check the first section in this question), I did not see anything. The data is not updated in the db.json file and even i didn't see any error in the console. Kindly help to to rectify the issue. So that i can proceed my learning.

Thanks in advance

Thanks
Manivannan